# can only throw exceptions in C# functions?

Tags: c#, exception

I've written a custom exception and want it to be thrown when the parking hours exceed 24hrs. I firstly placed the throw exception in the parent class property `HoursParked` but it never throws when I debug the program. Then I moved it to a function within the same class and it worked fine. Does it mean we can only throw exceptions in a function definition? Hope to get some insights into this as I don't fully understand the mechanism of exception handling even after resear

```
public class ParkingException : ApplicationException
    {
        public override string Message
        {
            get => "Your car has been towed away!";
        }
    }
```

```
public double HoursParked 
        { 
            get => _hoursParked;
            set
                if (_hoursParked > 24)
                {
                    throw new ParkingException();
                }
                else
                {
                    _hoursParked = Math.Ceiling(value);
                }
        }
```

```
public void DisplayTotalCost()
        {
            if(HoursParked > 24)
            {
                throw new ParkingException();
            }
        }
```

ching various documents. Thanks

Comment: It's not that, it's that you are checking against the previous value, not the incoming one.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (value > 24)` instead of `if (_hoursParked > 24)`? If we try to set a value that exceeds `24` we throw the exception. I can't see when `if(HoursParked > 24)` can be true: `HourParked` returns `_hoursParked` which is below `24`.

Comment: Also, decide on where to throw. If you throw in the setter, then the value of the prop can never be > 24h. And then the check in `DisplayTotalCost` would _always_ be false.

Comment: SIde note: I suggest throwing `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in set (we try to assign a value which is beyond the limits) and `InvalidOperationException` in `DisplayTotalCost` (we can't perform an operation due to instance state); you may want not to throw exception in the second case but print the message "Your car is towed away"

Comment: I'd actually consider this misuse of exceptions. The duration a vehicle is _in fact_ parked does not care for it to be illegal being longer than 24h. Nevertheless, it should be tracked as such, shouldn't it?

Comment: To expand on Fildor's point, you might need to use the `HoursParked` property to determine if it's in violation of posted signs. If you never allow it to be over 24 hours, it would never be in violation. Rather, the only thing that would be "out of range" would be negative values, unless you're going to predict how far in the future a car is going to be parked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, exceptions are designed for *exceptional* situations only. In our case it seems that we can have such behavior in the `set` only:

```
...
public double HoursParked { 
  get => _hoursParked;
  set {
    // if value is beoynd the expected range 0..24 we can't accept it
    // we can't correct the value: what should we do with -123 or 45678?
    // since we can't process the given value, we throw exception.
    // Please, note the name: we complain for value being out of range 
    if (value < 0 || value > 24)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), 
        "You can park from 0 to 24 hours only!");

   // value is valid, so we assign it
    _hoursParked = Math.Ceiling(value);
  }
}
   
public void DisplayTotalCost() {
  // We should not complain for _hoursParked here: 
  // it's assigned with set and have a valid value;
  // thus no exception is expected to be thrown.
  // If the car is towed, just display this fact:
  if (Math.Ceiling(_hoursParked) >= 24) { //TODO: Put the right condition here
    Console.Write("Sorry, your car is towed away");

    return;
  }

  //TODO: Compute and show the cost here
}
...
```

Comment: I disagree a little bit here. While values < 0 are impossible and would point to coding error, values > 24h just pose an illegal business constraint. So, it depends a little on definitions. Or maybe we should even have two different exception types...